# in Android written application in the Codenameone environment?

Tags: android, responsive-design, codenameone

Is it possible to adapt and integrate a in Android complete written application in the Codenameone environment? how far would that be possible? If yes, can we perform the same package structure?  What about the Adabtation Android's packages (including the Android functions) in Code Name One? Will it also retained the responsive design and the original resolution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt the code to use Codename One API's and not Android API's. The resulting app will run on Android, iOS etc. See http://www.codenameone.com/android.html

Comment: I already use Codename One. My question was, how can be integrated a in Android written project into the Codename One. Would that've ever been possible? For example, there are Android Classes that do not exist in Codename One. How easy it would be to implement these classes again in codename? Thanks.

Comment: Did you see native interfaces: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html most cn1lib's use those http://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html